# How to fill a listBox with the information of a form each time the 'register' button is clicked (Without BD)

Tags: c#, json, uwp

I want that when clicking on the *button 'Register'*, immediately show in a `listBox` the information previously entered, and thus with 'n' number of new records.

**I do not use BD**, I use `Newtonsoft.Json` to save the form data. But I want every `serializeObject` to be a new record represented in the `listBox`. I'm working on the **MainPage.xaml.cs** file.

*I am a complete newbie in c # and POO*, how could I do it? I appreciate your help. This I have advanced:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void RegistrerDebtor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Identification = TxtIdentification.Text;
        person.Name = TxtName.Text;
        person.LastName = TxtLastName.Text;
        person.Address = TxtAddress.Text;
        person.Phone = TxtPhone.Text;
        person.Email = TxtMail.Text;
        person.Latitude = TxtLatitude.Text;
        person.OriLat = CbxOrientationLat.Text;
        person.Longitude = TxtLongitude.Text;
        person.OriLon = CbxOrientationLon.Text;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);

        MessageDialog msgdialog = new MessageDialog(Convert.ToString(json), "Titulo dialogo");
        await msgdialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Identification { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string OriLat { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
    public string OriLon { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtIdentification"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtName"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtLastName"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtAddress"></TextBox>
    <TextBox x:Name="TxtPhone"></TextBox>
    ....
    ....
    ....
    <Button Content="Register" Click="RegistrerDebtor"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Make a public List<Person> and bind it to the ListBox, then each time you click the button add the the person object to the List

Comment: How do you enter the information? And where is the button in your example? Please provide more details.

Comment: @mm8, I edited the question, I put the Frm `xaml` with the respective fields and the button

Comment: @TheLastStark, That's exactly what I want, the problem is that I do not know how to do it :). Could you show me or explain how I should and can I do it, please?

Comment: @mm8 has done it for you. Also, in my earlier comment, I forgot it should be an ObservableCollection, not a List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set or bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` to an `ObservableCollection<Person>` and add the `Person` object to this one in the click event handler:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Person> _persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        listBox.ItemsSource = _persons;
    }

    private void RegistrerDebtor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Identification = TxtIdentification.Text;
        person.Name = TxtName.Text;
        person.LastName = TxtLastName.Text;
        person.Address = TxtAddress.Text;
        person.Phone = TxtPhone.Text;
        person.Email = TxtMail.Text;
        person.Latitude = TxtLatitude.Text;
        person.OriLat = CbxOrientationLat.Text;
        person.Longitude = TxtLongitude.Text;
        person.OriLon = CbxOrientationLon.Text;

        _persons.Add(person);
    }
}
```

You could then use an `ItemTemplate` to define the apperance of each `Person`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If you want to display a serialized string in the `ListBox`, you could simply change the type of the source collection and add `strings` to it instead of `Person` objects:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> _persons = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        listBox.ItemsSource = _persons;
    }

    private void RegistrerDebtor(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.Identification = TxtIdentification.Text;
        person.Name = TxtName.Text;
        person.LastName = TxtLastName.Text;
        person.Address = TxtAddress.Text;
        person.Phone = TxtPhone.Text;
        person.Email = TxtMail.Text;
        person.Latitude = TxtLatitude.Text;
        person.OriLat = CbxOrientationLat.Text;
        person.Longitude = TxtLongitude.Text;
        person.OriLon = CbxOrientationLon.Text;
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person, Formatting.Indented);
        _persons.Add(json);

    }
}
```

Then you won't need the `ItemTemplate`.